# How to record a webform submission ID in a CiviCRM field?

Tags: webform-civicrm

I'm using a webform to collect applications for an accreditation scheme. Usefully the webform submissions each have a unique submission ID that I can include in the webform-driven email notifications that get sent. And using webform-civicrm integration I can collect the data from the webform submission into CiviCRM for ongoing workflow.

What I want to do is to record the webform submission ID into a custom field in CiviCRM at the same time, so that I can then use it in further email notifications to the people involved. But the [submission] tokens are not available for form components - because the form isn't yet submitted so the values aren't available.

Any way to do this? Or alternatively create a unique ID number in CiviCRM, and then maybe use CiviRules to generate all of the emails?

It seems like such a trivial thing to have a unique reference number, but in Civi the only thing I can see that's useful is a Case ID number and I'd really rather not have to use cases for what is otherwise a very simple process.

Comment: wondering if we can see more of the workflow. are you wanting the webform submission id because you email folk with a link to go back and look at it? I am wondering what the value of the submission is v having all the data on eg an Activity and hence giving them a link to the webform with 'aid' in the url

Comment: Thanks Pete. I don't need to send people back to the webform. All i want is for each submission to have a unique reference ID that I can use through the entire workflow. For me it makes sense to use the submission ID as it is already there, but because I can't easily get that into a Civi field I can't then reference that ID in mails sent from Civi.

Comment: and having the link to the submission provided in the Activity won't suffice?

Answer (score 3):

there is an extension that allows you to create a CiviRule with trigger webform is submitted: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civiruleswebform. That might help you, although you probably then still have to create a little CiviRule action that stores the submission ID in the CiviCRM custom field.

Drop me a mail if you want to take this further?

Answer (score 1):

How about this for a unique-reference number:

CRMID-Number is a CiviCRM Custom field - Alphanumeric - Text
I've made it:
[node:nid]-[random:number]-[current-date:raw]

node id = 421
random number = 758398555
data raw is UNIX timestamp = 1543593293

[image]